# Objective C: How to use UIImage as a property in my model?

Tags: objective-c

I have a `Player` model:

Player.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Player : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *answers;

@end
```

Player.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Player.h"

@interface Player ()

@end

@implementation Player

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.answers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultProfileImage"]; // <-------------- error
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

However this displays the error: `Use of undeclared identifier 'UIImage'`

How would I use UIImage in my model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to import

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

So that UIImage is recognised